# How to smoothen a contour plot?

Tags: plotting, smoothing

I want to smoothen the following contour.

```
ContourPlot[
 10^b - (10^180/(10^m  10^23)^6)^(1/4)/Sqrt[ (((10^36)^(3/2))/(
   10^m  10^23 Sqrt[ 100]))] == 0, {m, -3, 15}, {b, -25, -2}, 
 ContourStyle -> {{Purple, Thickness[.01]}}]
```

Is there a way to do so?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try the option `MaxRecursion`

```
ContourPlot[
 10^b - (10^180/(10^m 10^23)^6)^(1/4)/Sqrt[(((10^36)^(3/2))/(10^m 10^23Sqrt[100]))] == 0, 
 {m, -3, 15}, {b, -25, -2}, 
 ContourStyle -> {{Purple, Thickness[.01]}}, 
 MaxRecursion -> 5]
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

```
10^b - (10^180/(10^m 10^23)^6)^(1/4)/Sqrt[(10^36)^(3/2)/(
   10^m 10^23 Sqrt[100])] == 0 // FullSimplify
```

get

```
10^b == (10^(-6 (-7 + m)))^(1/4)/Sqrt[10^(30 - m)]
```

Solve m

```
m /. Solve[10^b == (10^(-6 (-7 + m)))^(1/4)/Sqrt[10^(30 - m)], {m}]
```

get

```
{(-9 Log[10] - 2 Log[10^b])/(2 Log[10])}
```

Plot it

```
Plot[(-9 Log[10] - 2 Log[10^b])/(2 Log[10]), {b, -25, -2}]
```

[image]

This is m=f[b] , change to b=f[m]

```
Plot[InverseFunction[(-9 Log[10] - 2 Log[10^#])/(2 Log[10]) &][
  m], {m, -3, 15}]
```

[image]

---

And after simplify, we get

```
Plot[1/2 (-9 - 2 m), {m, -3, 15}]
```

，such a simple expression.

Comment: `Simplify[10^b - (10^180/(10^m 10^23)^6)^(1/4)/
   Sqrt[(((10^36)^(3/2))/(10^m 10^23 Sqrt[100]))], 
 Assumptions -> -25 <= b <= -2 && -3 <= m <= 15]`